# Prevent bots from spamming public web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have a public web service that fetches data from a jQuery call.  Because the users of my site are the public, they are not required to login and authenticate.  I have recently noticed that a bot seems to be repeatedly calling this web service, which is spiking my servers database.  I am not sure how to best prevent malicious users from spamming my web service, but still keep the service open and not require authentication.  I suppose I could send a password to the web service and only do the database call if the password is present, but because my JavaScript code calls the service, it would  be easy enough for a malicious actor to just view the source and copy the password.  How do folks typically deal with this issue?  An example of my code is below:

Javascript:

```
          return $.ajax({
            url: '/MyWebService.asmx/GetAllMetaData',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                //do stuff with the data
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#LoadingData').hide();
            }
        });
```

MyWebService.asmx

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")>
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class MyWebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function GetAllMetaData() As String
       Dim MetaData As New SearchMetaData
       MetaData.SomeField = DatabaseCallFunction()
       MetaData.AnotherField = DatabaseCallFunctionTwo()

       Dim serilaizedString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MetaData, Formatting.Indented)

       Return serilaizedString
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I really don't think there is a way to do this with out some sort of client side user entry.  Weather that be authentication or maybe a captcha

Comment: How many users do you have? There are ways to block the IP address if it's consistent. (Or whitelist the users IP).

Comment: Yeah, we are currently blocking the IP address but if they really want to cause damage, they can just change their IP address or use a VPN or something.  I was hoping there was a way to throttle the number or requests per minute or something.